# How to assign variables in loop For NodeJS

Tags: node.js, loops, for-loop

I have an array called `req.body.items`, which contains always one or more items. And I have to assign some variables according to the quantity of items that it has, like this:

```
for (x in req.body.items.length) {
    var width = req.body.items[x].dimensions.width * 100;
    var height = req.body.items[x].dimensions.height * 100;
    var weight = req.body.items[x].dimensions.weight;
    var depth = req.body.items[x].dimensions.depth * 100;
    var quantity = req.body.items[x].quantity;
    var sku = req.body.items[x].sku;
};
```

The problem is that I will have as many "widthes" as items, so if I have 3 items, I must have 3 widthes. And I don't know how to do so. I have searched this, but I only found in Javascript for frontend, I need it to create an API.

It could be just like `var width0, var width1, var width2, etc`.

Comment: Please read the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide more information in order to get someone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let req={
  body: {
    items: [
      {
        dimensions: {
          width: 1,
          height:3,
          weight:4,
          quantity:7
        }
      },
      {
        dimensions: {
          width: 5,
          height:2,
          weight:6,
          quantity:8
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

let dimensions = req.body.items.reduce((result,item)=>{
    Object.entries(item.dimensions).map(([key,value])=>(!!result[key] ? result[key]=[...result[key], value*100]: result[key]=[value*100]));
    return result; 
  },{});

console.log(dimensions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something like this:

```
var width = [];
var height = [];
var weight = [];
var depth = [];
var quantity = [];
var sku = [];
for (let x in req.body.items.length) {
  width.push(req.body.items[x].dimensions.width * 100);
  height.push(req.body.items[x].dimensions.height * 100);
  weight.push(req.body.items[x].dimensions.weight);
  depth.push(req.body.items[x].dimensions.depth * 100);
  quantity.push(req.body.items[x].quantity);
  sku.push(req.body.items[x].sku);
};
```

Now, `width`, `height` ... are `arrays` conaining your data.